# estimating coefficients of multiple regression with keraregressor

Tags: python, linear-regression, sequential

I used a sequential model and kerasregressor to create multiple regression for the variables x1 and x2. the model worked successfully and I could predict y for test data correctly but now I want to derive coefficients of this regression. what do I do?`

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO! What is the exact problem that you are facing? Have you implemented multiple regression with Keras and are stuck with some problem with estimating the coefficients? Please post more details.

Comment: yes, I have used regression-based deep learning to find any relationship between two dependent variables x1 and x2, and the independent variable y. so that, I have applied a sequential model and kerasregressor estimator for creating the regression relation. now I need the coefficients of this regression. how to calculate the coefficients using a sequential model?